# Insert a copy of a node in a list (with condition)

Tags: c, list, insert, singly-linked-list

The exercise asks to insert a copy of a value x (which is also the value to search in the list), but only if the position is multiple of another value n. It is not specified whether the copy should be inserted before or after the x value.

My problem is that the copy is not inserted in all cases. I think the problem is that when I insert the new node, the counter of the list positions also counts this new value, reporting an incorrect result.

How can I solve the problem? Or am I making a mistake?

I'm learning. maybe my attempt is completely wrong and for this reason I ask for at least a decent explanation so that I can improve.

my code:

```
    struct data
{
    int d;
    struct data *next;
};

typedef struct data Node;

Node *newnode(void)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(Node));
}

Node *creat_list()
{
    Node *lis, *p, *last;
    int x;

    printf("\n insert data: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(x <= 0)
    {
        lis = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last = newnode();

        lis = last;
        last->d = x;
        last->next = NULL;

        printf(" insert data: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        while(x > 0)
        {
            p = newnode();
            p->d = x;
            p->next = NULL;
            last->next = p;
            last = p;
            printf(" insert data: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);

        }
    }
    return (lis);
}

void print_list(Node *lis)
{
    printf("\n List: \n");
    printf(" -> ");

    while(lis != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", lis->d);
        printf(" -> ");
        lis = lis->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n\n");
}

void insertCopy(int x, int n, Node **lis)
{
    int pos = 1;

    Node *p, *head;

    head = *lis;


    if ((head->d == x) && (pos % n == 0))
    {
            p = newnode();
            p->d = x;
            p->next = head;
            *lis = p;
    }

    if (head->next != NULL)
    {
        pos = 2;

        while(head->next != NULL)
        {
            if ((head->next->d == x) && (pos % n == 0))
            {
                p = newnode();
                p->d = x;
                p->next = head->next;
                head->next = p;
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->next;
            }
            pos++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{   
    Node *l1;

    int x = 1;
    int n = 3;

    l1 = creat_list();

    print_list(l1);

    insertCopy(x, n, &l1);

    print_list(l1);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

Input:

```
2 3 1 6 1 2 2 6 1 5 0
```

gives

List:

```
2->3->1->6->1->2->2->6->1->5->NULL
```

With

```
x = 1, n = 3;
```

Expected Output is:

```
2->3->1->1->6->1->2->2->6->1->1->5->NULL
```

My Output is:

```
2->3->1->1->6->1->2->2->6->1->5->NULL
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195156/discussion-on-question-by-sabaudian-insert-a-copy-of-a-node-in-a-list-with-cond).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more problems in your code but the one you are asking for (according to your example) is that you only get one extra node while you expected two extra nodes.

Expected:

```
2->3->1->1->6->1->2->2->6->1->1->5->NULL
```

Actual:

```
2->3->1->1->6->1->2->2->6->1->5->NULL
                           ^^^
                        A node is missing here
```

The problem is the way you handle `head` when you insert the extra node.

Try to change this:

```
        if ((head->next->d == x) && (pos % n == 0))
        {
            p = newnode();
            p->d = x;
            p->next = head->next;
            head->next = p;
        }
```

into

```
        if ((head->next->d == x) && (pos % n == 0))
        {
            p = newnode();
            p->d = x;
            p->next = head->next;
            head->next = p;
            head=p->next;       // Add this line
        }
```

The problem with your original code was that you didn't move `head` correctly. Therefore the counter `pos` got out of sync with the original list.

Comment: @Sabaudian The problem with your question was that to start with you only posted **expected** output but did not post **actually** output. If you had posted both to start with, we could have helped you sooner

Comment: @Sabaudian What  4386427 is saying is correct. And if you had provided an MRE like Bodo asked in the very first comment, we would have noticed that and given you an answer in minutes rather than hours. It was called MCVE before, and you can read about the importance [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: @Sabaudian Also, you would be surprised how many times the process of creation an MRE has made me NOT posting a question, because the very process made me realize the solution. It is indeed a very great debugging tool.